# Getting finger print bytes on real time events from zkteco device using zkemkeeper

Tags: c#, winforms, fingerprint, zkemkeeper

hi i am working on a application developed in c# 
using zkemkeeper sdk and Machine is Zkteco TFT

every thing is working fine and all events are working but i need to bypass device verification when some one swipe his finger i want to get finger template and want to verify from database SQL

```cs
zkemkeeper.CZKEM objzkem_OnFinger = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();

bool isconnected = objzkem_OnFinger.Connect_Net("192.168.10.6", Convert.ToInt32("4370"));

if (objzkem_OnFinger.RegEvent(1, 65535))
{
 objzkem_OnFinger.OnFinger += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFinger);                
}


and want to get finger when some one swipe his finger on scanner


private void axCZKEM1_OnFinger()
      {
          // label1.Text = "OK";
          byte[] TmpData = new byte[20000];
          int with = 500;
          int lenth = 800;
          bool fulimage = false;
          string path = @"F:\3.png";
          byte a = 1 ;
        bool result2 =   objzkem_OnFinger.EnableDevice(1, true);
          bool result = objzkem_OnFinger.CaptureImage(fulimage, ref with, ref lenth, ref a, path);

      }

but capture image always return false
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, Now I need your scenario, did you fix it?